# if $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$ does $f_n'(x)$ converge uniformly to $f'(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let [a,b] denote a finite interval and consider a sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=0}^\infty$ in $C^1([a,b])$. if $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$, does $\{f_n'(x)\}$ converge uniformly to $f'(x)$?

My intuition for this problem is that the converse is true, but I'm not sure how to justify this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

$$f_n(x) = \frac1{n} \sin(nx)$$

$(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$ (on $\Bbb R$), but $f_n'$ doesn't even converge pointwise

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! Is it possible to strengthen the assumptions so that $f_n'(x)$ goes to $f'(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

One may consider
$$
f_n(x):=\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n},\quad x \in [0,1],
$$ we have, for $n\geq1$,
$$
\left|f_n(x)-|x|\right|=\frac{\frac1n}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}+|x|}\leq \frac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$ thus the convergence of $\left\{ f_n \right\}$ is uniform over $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, we have
$$
  f'_n(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}} \longrightarrow f'(x)=
    \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $\,x=0$,} \\[2ex]
1 & \text{if $\,0<x\leq1$,}
\end{cases}
$$
the latter convergence **can't** be uniform since each $f'_n$ is continuous over $[0,1]$ but $f'$ is not.